# Run a function before/after magit runs git

Tags: magit, hooks

I'd like to run a function before magit runs git, and another one after magit runs git. I see `magit-pre-start-git-hook` but I don't see any post-finish-git hook. How can I run commands before and after magit runs git?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to write `before` advice for `magit-process-finish` (and to submit a feature request).  Note also `magit-pre-call-git-hook` for synchronous calls.  Be careful though -- the "pre" hook for the async case has no process object, and async processes might not finish in the order you started them.

Comment: Magit runs `git` a lot. Doing something every time that happens probably isn't a good idea. What do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magit runs git a lot. Doing something every time that happens probably isn't a good idea. What do you want to accomplish?

---

That being said you can make Magit do something before running `git` by advising all or some of the functions that run `git`. I strongly recommend you only advice some of these functions or even just the commands that you actually want to do something before running `git`. I cannot tell you which functions you have to advice because you didn't say what you want to accomplish.

To find all functions that run `git` grep for `magit-git-executable`.